# Retrofit sending a java pojo in the form of fieldset

Tags: android, retrofit

I am developing a comment function in my app, and the web api require data formed like：

```
comment[title]
comment[content]
```

In my java code, I define a comment class:

```
public String title;
public String content;
```

Now I use '@Body', but it generate *title=xyz&content=xyz*
How to send the data in the right way, only @FieldMap, any way better?

Comment: what json structure does your server want?

Comment: "comment" : {"title": "xyz", "content": "xyz"}

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate POJO classes for example if you are using GSON

```
Comment.java

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Comment {

@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private String title;
@SerializedName("content")
@Expose
private String content;

public String getTitle() {
return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
this.title = title;
}

public String getContent() {
return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
this.content = content;
}


CommentSerialize.java

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class CommentSerialize{

@SerializedName("comment")
@Expose
private Comment comment;

public Comment getComment() {
return comment;
}

public void setComment(Comment comment) {
this.comment = comment;
}

}
```

And send the request using retrofit like this for example

```
@POST(...)
Call<...> postComment(@Body CommentSerialize comment)
```

Hope this will help you.